# Why can't you use a local SqlCommand variable in a using statement

Tags: c#, .net

I'm not sure if i'm just having a dumb moment here or I generally do not understand but can someone explain to me why this will run:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

public void SomeMethod()
{
    using(SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConnection"].ConnectionString))
    {
        using(SqlCommand qry = new SqlCommand(someSqlString, dbConnection))
        {
             dbConnection.Open();
             using(SqlDataReader reader = qry.ExecuteReader())
             {
                ...
             }
         }
     }
}
```

and this will not run throwing an InvalidOperationException (The ConnectionString property has not been initialized) when it hits `dbConnection.Open()`:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

private SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConnection"].ConnectionString);

public void SomeMethod()
{
    using(dbConnection)
    {
        using(SqlCommand qry = new SqlCommand(someSqlString, dbConnection))
        {
             dbConnection.Open();
             using(SqlDataReader reader = qry.ExecuteReader())
             {
                ...
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: It probably has something to do with the fact that a using statement is going to dispose of that connection, and your variable will never get re-instantiated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second example **will** run (at least it should)... but *only the first time you call `SomeMethod()`.* This is because after the first call to the method, you have Dispose()'d the connection object.

ADO.Net has a built-in feature called [Connection Pooling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399543.aspx) that intelligently re-uses the underlying database connection resources. For the most part, *you should not try to use the same `Dbconnection` object over and over.* Instead, just re-use the connection string, create the connection objects as you need them, and Dispose() of them as soon as possible when done. Otherwise, you are conflicting with the built-in connection pooling and making things worse, rather than better.

In other words, the first sample is the *correct* way to do this. It's faster and more efficient than the second, even though the second seems to save you an object allocation here and there.

About the only time you should try to re-use a connection object is when you're going to have a bunch of queries in a tight loop, such that you might open the connection once, execute a bunch of queries one after the other, and then close it when you've finished the whole batch. And even then, most of the time when I've seen this the code was better off refactored in some way to group the sql statements into a single batch.

Comment: Yes that makes sense, thanks for the insight! I didn't make it clear in my question that this was not the first time I was trying to use the connection but that is exactly what was happening

Comment: Seems someone disagreed, but didn't feel like sharing why?

Answer (score 1):

MSDN explains:

> You can instantiate the resource object and then pass the variable to
>   the using statement, but this is not a best practice. In this case,
>   the object remains in scope after control leaves the using block even
>   though it will probably no longer have access to its unmanaged
>   resources. In other words, it will no longer be fully initialized. If
>   you try to use the object outside the using block, you risk causing an
>   exception to be thrown. For this reason, it is generally better to
>   instantiate the object in the using statement and limit its scope to
>   the using block.

So, to simplify it...
`using` statement ensures that the object will be disposed after code block is executed and will ensure the object will go out of scope. So, in your second example, you're using it wrong, and the connection is no longer managed so it behavies unpredictably.